# Javascript error if element not on the page. using vanilla js

Tags: javascript

I recently use jQuery in my projects. But now I want to move on vanilla js. The problem i am facing is javascript error message when element not on the page. so I am using if condition if element exists on the page. The things are why write over and over again if condition. If there is any solution and structure for vanilla js projects. 
I don't want to write if condition for every element

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var element = document.querySelector('.element');
    if(element) {
        // do something
    }
    var element2 = document.querySelector('.element2');
    if(element2) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by this term `javascript error message when element not on the page`?

Comment: If element is null what do you want to do else? Explain more clearly what you want to achieve.

Comment: I don't want to write if condition for every element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code work for me.

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

  var element = document.querySelectorAll('.element');
  element.forEach(element => element.classList.add('any-class'));

});
```

Comment: Your first solution will only work if **both** elements exist. What if one exists, the other not?

Comment: You are right. I check & remove the code from the answer.